# F# creating smaller tuple using Seq.map

Tags: f#

I have written this F# code:

```
let tuples = [|("A",1,0);("A",2,3);("A",3,6)|]
let tupleSubset =
tuples
|> Seq.map(fun values -> 
    values.[0],
    values.[2])
printfn "%A" tupleSubset
```

I am getting: *The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type constraints*

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's unclear to me why this was down-voted. It seems like a legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way around the error you are getting would be the following:

```
let tuples = [|("A",1,0); ("A",2,3); ("A",3,6)|]
let tupleSubset = tuples |> Seq.map (fun (a, b, c) -> a, b)
printfn "%A" tupleSubset
```

As to why you are getting the error: note that the kind of index dereferencing you are attempting with `values.[0]` and `values.[1]` works for arrays, dictionaries, etc., but not for tuples, whereas each `values` has the type `string * int * int`.

Since you don't need the third element of the tuple, you can even choose not to bind it to a symbol, by writing the second line as follows:

```
let tupleSubset = tuples |> Seq.map (fun (a, b, _) -> a, b)
```

Comment: What is the type constraint hint trying to tell him? My F# is rusty.

Comment: @neontapir, my guess is that upon seeing the notation `x.[n]` the type inferencing mechanism expected one of the data types I mentioned above, for which this notation works, but its computation of the type up to that point failed to turn up one of those types.

Comment: As a followup, I am implementing this pattern in my real application.  A function is returning a Seq<DateTime*DateTime* string*string*string*string>.  When I reference this function in another function, I am getting a "The type 'unit -> Seq<DateTime*DateTime* string*string*string*string> is not compatable with the type Seq<a> when I try Seq.Map.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JamieDixon - add a `()` where you reference it to call the function

Comment: OMG - that was it!  Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of Shredderoy is correct, accessing an element by its index is reserved to arrays, which are contiguous blocks of memory.

For tuple, if you want to access the values of a tuple in F# the general method is to pattern match

```
let tuple = a,b,c
let (x,y,z) = tuple
```

In the case of *pair*, the function `fst` and `snd` also give a similar access

PS : In you initial array, you dont need to use parenthesis, as the compiler recognizes the `,` as a tuple

Comment: This isn't quite right - you can use the `.[]` operator on any type with an indexed property named `Item`.  Most of these tend to be backed by arrays but that's not required (e.g. for the silly example `type T() = member this.Item with get(n:string) = n.Length`, `T().["test"]` returns `4`).